# Mail delivery failed :returning message to sender

Tags: email

I got this bounce back email whenever try to send to a specific sender..
Any help would be appreciate..Thanks :D

mail content:

```
This message was created automatically by mail delivery software.
A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its
recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed:
example@example.com.mm
No Such User Here

Reporting-MTA: dns; mail.example.net
Action: failed
Final-Recipient: rfc822;example@example.com.mm
Status: 5.0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless there is something odd going on, the bounce back message is clearly telling you that the email address "example@example.com.mm" doe not exist.  Perhaps "No Such User Here" is not the best wording, but it means that the email address is non-existant.

Is the .mm at the end of the email address part of the problem?  Are you actually sending email to Myanmar?

I have never seen this bounceback message when the email address actually existed.  Since this is unusual, I would send the email headers to the ISP of the intended recipient, since it is highly likely that is where the problem exists, and ask them to investigate.  Also, I do think that you can get the same message if the users Inbox is full.  Ask the intended recipient about that.

Comment: yep.This email is actually exist.

Comment: Here is an article [link](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/email/bounceback-errors/fixing-no-such-user-here) about troubleshooting these errors.  If they are intermittent, I wonder if one of the Nameserver values or MX records is wrong, so only when those are in-force does the email bounce.  If you gave us the actual email address, we could check for some things.

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on.Neither Nameserver values or MX records is wrong.Also recipient mail inbox is not full enough.Anyway, thank you for your patient help it is really helpful :D @MikeA

Answer (score 0):

the problem has to do with your websites ***DKIM and SPF keys*** (**Email deliverability in CPanel**), if they are not added to the server it cannot verify the authenticity of your email.
The best solution is to contact your server support or CPanel support to fix the issue. There is almost nothing you can do via programming.

I had this issue and I spoke to my server's support team and it was fixed

[image: Email deliverability not valid]

At this point my email deliverability has not been marked as **VALID**, so the email
***Mail delivery failed :returning message to sender*** kept persisting.

so I spoke to the server support team as the tooltip in the image suggested and it was finally fixed

[image: fixed DKIM key]

if you noticed the ***VALID*** mark there